# Rails - Display loop only if certain criteria is met

Tags: ruby-on-rails, loops

I have a project_todo model with a boolean attribute 'status'. How would I display on the index page a loop that only lists project todos that have a status of false?

The regular loop that lists all project todos looks like this:

```
<% @project.project_todos.each do |todo|%>
    <li data-id="<%= todo.id %>">
        <%= todo.title %>
    </li>
<% end %>
```

And I was playing around with a loop that only displays the todos IF the status is false by doing this:

```
<% @project.project_todos {status = "f"}.each do |todo|%>
    <li data-id="<%= todo.id %>">
        <%= todo.title %>
    </li>
<% end %>
```

Am I anywhere close?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This will loop only on the project_todos that have a `status == false` :

```
<% @project.project_todos.select{|project_todos| project_todos.status == false}.each do |todo|%>
    <li data-id="<%= todo.id %>">
        <%= todo.title %>
    </li>
<% end %>
```

OR, **a better solution**: you can do the following, and let ActiveRecord filter the `project_todos` itself:

```
<% @project.project_todos.where(status: false).each do |todo|%>
    <li data-id="<%= todo.id %>">
        <%= todo.title %>
    </li>
<% end %>
```

**In extansion**:

You can create a scope like following:

```
class ProjectTodo < ActiveRecord::Base
  #...
  scope :with_status, lambda{ |status| where(status: status) }
  #...
end
```

And use it like this:

```
@project.project_todos.with_status(status: false) # Returns the project_todos with a status == false and belonging to the @project
```

Comment: Thanks, that works perfect! Now I need to find a way to toggle the status when a todo list item is dragged into a certain div, using the jQuery sortable function.

Comment: You should accept an answer if it fits your request. About the status toggle, you can use on the model: `status = !self.status` in the model method called `toggle_status` for example. (note that `!nil #=> true`, so if the status is nil, it counts as `false` for the toggle and won't raise an error)

Comment: Ah sorry, I'm new to the Stack Overflow scene. I'll play around w/ the code you just posted. Thanks for all your help!

Answer (score 1):

Don't put too much logic in your views if you can help it.  In this case, you can create a scope on `ProjectTodo` to filter based on the `status` field.

```
class ProjectTodo < ActiveRecord::Base
  scope :inactive, where(status: false)
  #...
end
```

Then in your view, you can do

```
<% @project.project_todos.inactive.each do |todo|%>
    <li data-id="<%= todo.id %>">
        <%= todo.title %>
    </li>
<% end %>
```